# List of random variables whose probability density function satisfies a certain inequality

Tags: probability, random-variables

For a continuous random variable $X$ with a probability density function (pdf) of $f(\cdot)$, consider the following inequality
\begin{equation}
\frac{f(x+y)}{f(x)}\ge \frac{f(x+y+z)}{f(x+z)},
\end{equation}
where $0<x,y,z.$

I checked this inequality and it holds for Uniform, Exponential and Normal distributions. Is there a way to frame this inequality more generally? That is, is there a special name for this property? Or is there any well-known property that ensures the validity of the above inequality?

Thanks!

Comment: This is true if and only if the logarithm of $f$ is a concave function.

Comment: That is equivalent to $f''(x)f(x)\leq f'(x)^2$, when $f$ has a second derivative. (Really, only requires this for $x>0$.)

Comment: Thanks for your comments Thomas... Could you elaborate more on your second comment that "Really, only requires this for $x>0$" ? Thanks!

Comment: Since you only wanted it for $x,y,z$ positive, the condition needs only be true for $x$ positive.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews can you explain how does $f^{''}(x) f(x) \le f^{'}(x)^{2}$ imply the relationship that I am looking for?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think I figured out the link between log concave function and the above relationship. Suppose $f(\cdot)$ is log concave, then for $\theta=\frac{y}{y+z}$, one can argue that $\log f(\theta(x+y+z) + (1-\theta)x ) \ge \theta \log( f(x+y+z) ) + (1-\theta) \log (f(x))$. Similarly, $\log f( (1- \theta) (x+y+z) + \theta x ) \ge (1-\theta) \log( f(x+y+z) ) + \theta \log (f(x))$. Combining this two inequalities, we show that $\log f(x+y) + \log f(x+z) \ge \log f(x+y+z) + \log f(x)$ which implies the inequality I was looking for. Thanks for the tip!